# How to run a AppleScript from VBA using AppleScriptTask

Tags: excel, vba, applescript

My goal is to have VBA code run a script to then select a validation cell and show the drop down list items.

VBA:

```vb
Sub Test() 
Dim RunMyScript As Boolean   
Dim FilePathName As String  
FilePathName = "/Users/scott/Library/Application   Scripts/com.microsoft.Excel/Validation Drop Down Arrow Script.scpt"  
RunMyScript = AppleScriptTask("Validation Drop Down Arrow   Script.scpt", "ArrowDown", FilePathName)  
End Sub
```

Script:

```
on ArrowDown()  
tell application "Microsoft Excel"  
activate  
delay 0.1   
select range "G2"  
tell application "System Events" to key code 125 using option down  
end tell  
end ArrowDown
```

Note: The script works when run from script editor but fails when I try to call it from VBA.